# Azure CLI: Downloading a pipeline run artifact from within a container

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

According to the docs, the following syntax can be used to download a pipeline artifact:

```bash
az pipelines runs artifact download --organization <organization> --project <project> --run-id <run-id> --artifact-name <artifact-name> --path .
```

The problem is that all our artifacts are within a container and sub-container.

If I fill in all the values, and specify the container as , I get an error that the artifact was found, but it is a container. I understand that downloading an entire container is not supported.

But I want to get a single file: container/sub-container/filename.json.

If I specify the artifact-name as above, using either slashes or backslashes, it says it can't find the artifact.

So, how can one download a file contained within a container?

Answer (score 0):

**According to this official [**MS document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/runs/artifact?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-runs-artifact-download%28azure-devops%29)**

```bash
az pipelines runs artifact download --artifact-name
```

contains parameter to specify entire artifact-name and not the path to specify folder or sub-folders. As a workaround you can download the entire artifact in one path and then copy the specific file in a desired location like below:-

**Copy entire artifact:-**

```bash
az pipelines runs artifact download --organization https://dev.azure.com/Orgname --project projectname --run-id runid --artifact-name drop --path pathtodownloadtheartifact
```

[image]

Copy the specific file to the path from the downloaded artifact like below:-

**Option:-**

```bash
# Download the artifact
az pipelines runs artifact download --artifact-name Artifactname --path /path/to/download/location --run-id runID

download_path="/path/to/download/location/MyArtifact" #Downloaded artifact path
destination_path="/path/to/destination" #Another path to copy specific file

#Create another path dir if it does not exist
mkdir -p "$destination_path"

# Copy all .txt files to another destination path
cp "$download_path"/*.txt "$destination_path"
```